# Entity Framework 6, Update-Database -verbose command is not constructing the correct filepath to save my mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework 6.4 is not properly constructing the filepath it requires to create my `.mdf` file. For instance, when I run the following command in NuGet PM console:

```
update-database -Verbose
```

I get the following error:

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) 
>   while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\TomerNinjaDB.mdf'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

The file path should be `C:\Users\Tomer\NinjaDB.mdf`.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it? I pretty much want to tell EF6 where to save these things, because directly under my username isn't too appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this issue in the official support site for local Db, exactly the same:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/4096875/fix-access-is-denied-error-when-you-try-to-create-a-database-in-sql-se

I don't know the version you are using of Sql Server Express, update it could be the solution for that, according to the link.

Comment: Brilliant, I spent so long trying to find the answer. Thank you!